# What functions can be the limit of the CDF of the average of n IID random variables as n grows without bound?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, convergence-divergence, random-variables

Suppose that we have a probability distribution $D$. Define $F_n$ to be the cumulative probability distribution function of the average of $n$ independent random variables drawn from $D$, and define $F_* (x) = \lim_{n\to \infty}F_n (x)$. I've become interested in the question of what functions $F_*$ might possibly be. I've come up with two classes of functions and three individual functions that $F_*$ might be equal to, but I haven't yet been able to determine whether any others are possible.

If the Central Limit Theorem applies to $D$, and it has mean $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma$, then for sufficiently large values of $n$, $F_n$ is approximately the cumulative distribution function of $\mathcal{N}(\mu, \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt n})$. So in this case, $F_*(x)$ is $0$ when $x\lt\mu$,  $1$ when $x\gt\mu$, and I'm pretty sure it's always $0.5$ when $x=\mu$.

If $D$ is a degenerate distribution which always takes the value $v$, then the average of any number of variables drawn from that distribution will always be $v$, so all the $F_n$ will be the same as the cumulative distribution function of the original distribution. Therefore, $F_*(x)$ is $0$ when $x\lt v$ and $1$ when $x\ge v$.

If $D$ is a distribution with infinite expected value, such as the payout of the game from the [St. Petersburg paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/St._Petersburg_paradox), then the average of $n$ values drawn from that distribution will become arbitrarily likely to exceed any specific number as $n\to \infty$, so $F_*(x)=0$ for all $x$.

Likewise, if $D$ has an expected value of negative infinity, then $F_*(x)=1$ for all $x$.

By modifying the game from the St. Petersburg paradox a bit, I think I can also get $F_*(x)=0.5$ for all $x$. (The basic idea is to make the payout grow so fast with the number of coin flips that the total of $n$ payouts tends to be approximately equal to the largest payout, then switch the payout to negative with 50% probability. I could go into detail about why I think this works, but it would probably double the size of this question.)

Other than these two classes of functions and three individual constant functions, I haven't been able to find any other likely candidates, but I also haven't been able to find any reason why it should be impossible for $F_*$ to be anything else, as long as $0\le F_*(x)\le 1$ for all $x$ and $F_*$ is monotonically nondecreasing. (I do at least suspect that $F_*(x)$ is always well-defined for all $x$, but I'm not sure how to prove that the values of $F_n(x)$ must converge for all $x$ no matter what distribution we choose, so I could be wrong.)

So my question is: Can we conclude anything else about what kinds of functions are or are not possible for $F_*$? In particular: Is it possible for $F_*(x)$ to be anything other than $0$, $0.5$, or $1$? Is it possible for $F_*(x)$ to be strictly greater than zero and less than one in a region containing more than one value of $x$, without having to expand that region to the whole number line?

Comment: If $D$ is the standard [Cauchy-distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_distribution#Properties) then $F_n$ does not depend from $n$. So $F_{*}=F_1$

Comment: Do you know about "Stable distributions" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_distribution)?  The classic reference is Gnedenko and Kolmogorov, cited by the Wikipedia article.